# Why is my grid element in another grid place then it should?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Why is my grid area D flowing into my grid area A? I don't really know why this is happening so please help!

```css
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70px 125px;
    grid-template-rows: 20px 16px 42px 20px 16px 42px;
    grid-template-areas: "A B"
                         "A C"
                         "A ."
                         "D E"
                         "D F"
                         "D .";
    width: 100vw;
    margin-top: 30px;
    justify-content: center;
}

#clothing1-div {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
    z-index: -1;
}

#clothing1-div:hover {
    background-color: rgb(209, 209, 209);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(94, 94, 94);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(94, 94, 94);
}

#clothing1-img {
    width: 60px;
    grid-area: A;
}

#clothing1-link {
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    grid-area: B;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#clothing1-pris {
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    grid-area: C;
}

#clothing2-div {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 69px;
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
    z-index: -1;
}

#clothing2-div:hover {
    background-color: rgb(209, 209, 209);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(94, 94, 94);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(94, 94, 94);
}

#clothing2-img {
    width: 60px;
    grid-area: D;
}

#clothing2-link {
    grid-area: E;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#clothing2-pris {
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    grid-area: F;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
            <a href="#"><img src="/sticky/imgs/Svart Hoodie framsida PNG.png" alt="black-zip-up" id="clothing1-img"></a>
            <a href="#" id="clothing1-link">black zip-up</a>
            <a href="#"><img src="/sticky/imgs/Lila Hoodie framsida PNG.png" alt="purple-zip-up" id="clothing2-img"></a>
            <a href="#" id="clothing2-link">purple zip-up</a>
            <p id="clothing1-pris">500sek</p>
            <p id="clothing2-pris">500sek</p>
            <div onclick="location.href='#'" style="cursor:pointer;" id="clothing1-div"></div>
            <div onclick="location.href='#'" style="cursor:pointer;" id="clothing2-div"></div>
        </div>
```

I really don't know I expected my grid area D to be in it's place but it isn't? As described earlier i want my element in the grid to be where they are suppost to be mainly grid area D staying in it's area. What i tried is moving stuff around and placing 2 dummy element in the punctuated grid area but none have worked.

Comment: Can you share demo?

Comment: You haven't put the a (anchor) elements which hold the images into any particular grid position so they take the first one that fits. You have put the relevant ids into the children (the img elements) and so their placement won't be picked up by the grid settings.

Comment: Thanks A Haworth!